# Styling HTML helpers ASP.NET MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

If I have an HTML helper like so:

```
Name:<br />
<%=Html.TextBox("txtName",20) %><br />
```

How do I apply a CSS class to it? Do I have to wrap it in a span? Or do I need to somehow utilize the HtmlAttributes property of the helper?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can pass it into the TextBox call as a parameter.

```
Name:<br/>    
<%= Html.TextBox("txtName", "20", new { @class = "hello" }) %>
```

This line will create a text box with the value 20 and assign the class attribute with the value hello.  I put the @ character in front of the class, because class is a reserved keyword.  If you want to add other attributes, just separate the key/value pairs with commas.

Answer (score 14):

This is how to add a class and a style on the same element...

"x" being the model passed to the view with a property of TextBoxID

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TextBoxID, new { @class = "SearchBarSelect", style = "width: 20px; background-color: green;" })
```

Answer (score 4):

I did some research and came across this article that seems to have a solution to your question.

**Ajax Control Toolkit with ASP.NET MVC#**

source: jimzimmerman

**ARTICLE LINK**

http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=330

**QUOTE**

> So basically if you put the class name
>   TextboxWatermark on any textbox input
>   with the title you like to show as the
>   watermark like this:
>
> ```
> <input type="text" class"TextboxWatermark" name="username" id="username" title="Must be at least 6 chars" />
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> <%= Html.TextBox("username", new { @class = "TextboxWatermark", @title = "Must be at least 6 chars" }) %>
> ```
>
> What is nice about the second option
>   is that you get the added benefit of
>   getting the View Engine to fill out
>   the value of the textbox if there is
>   an item in ViewData of the
>   ViewData.Model that has a var named
>   'username'.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `htmlAttributes` parameter with an anonymous type, like tihs:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("txtName","20", new { @class = "test"}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

the helper implementation

```
public static class LabelExtensioncs
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Alarm(this HtmlHelper helper, string target, string text)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<p class='alert' style='background-color: #b8f89d;border-radius: 5px;width: 100%;'><b>{0}</b><br /><i>{1}</i></p>", target, text));
    }    
}
```

the usage in view section

```
@Html.Alarm("Title", "please unsure your card no is invisible in your authorized information")
```

the result
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Theres no need to use span, because its not dynamic.

Css:

```
.testClass {
color: #1600d3;
}
```

View (Index):

```
@Html.TextBox("expression", "Text to show.", new { @class = "testClass" })
```

if you need dynamic options you can use for example:

CSS:

```
.test class{
background: #ffffff;
}
```

Controller (Index for test):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
ViewBag.vbColor = "#000000";
return View();
}
```

View (Index):

```
<div>
<span>
@Html.TextBox("expression", "Text to show.", new 
{ @class = "testClass", @style="color: " + 
@ViewBag.vbColor })
</span>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Is it that much more work?

Comment: For devloper no, but for Designer YES.